# Regular Expression to break row with comma separated values into distinct rows

Tags: regex, csv

I have a file with many rows. Each row has a column which may contain comma separated values. I need each row to be distinct (ie no comma separated values).

Here is an example row:

```
AB  AB10,AB11,AB12,AB15,AB16,AB21,AB22,AB23,AB24,AB25,AB99  ABERDEEN    Aberdeenshire
```

The columns are comma separated (Postcode area, Postcode districts, Post town, Former postal county).

So the above row would get turned into:

```
AB  AB10    ABERDEEN    Aberdeenshire
AB  AB11    ABERDEEN    Aberdeenshire
AB  AB12    ABERDEEN    Aberdeenshire
...
...
```

I tried the following but it didn't work...

```
(.+)\t(([0-9A-Z]+),)+\t(.+)\t(.+)
```

Comment: I'm using BBEdit at the moment which is GREP powered... I believe it's Perl compatible. If not, I can switch to VIM or any suggested editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that RegEx are not be the best way but this should work hopefully if that's all you have available to you. (Done repeatedly until there are no more matches)

**Edit**

Updated with the OP's final solution from the comments.

```
Find: (.+)\t([^,\s]+),([^\t]+)\t(.+)
Replace: \1\t\2\t\4\r\1\t\3\t\4
```

Comment: That works very well - thanks... This is a slight modification which worked a little better. Thanks!

Find: "(.+)\t([^,\s]+),([^\t]+)\t(.+)"
Replace: "\1\t\2\t\4\r\1\t\3\t\4"

EDIT: Seems these comments cant contain markup...

Comment: Yes the penny just dropped that your fields were tab delimited and I had just come back to update my post. Glad you spotted it!

Comment: @Nick RE: Markup in the comments you can do a limited amount. See the accepted answer here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/apply-markup-code-in-comments

Answer (score 0):

I agree with stakx that this doesn't sound like a good place for regexes.

I would write a small program instead which read each line, split the line into columns, split each relevant column into a list of values, and then iterated over all combinations of those, outputting a line each time.

Assuming it's only that one column which can have multiple tokens, it would basically look like this:

```
while not InputFile.EndOfFile:
  line = InputFile.readline();
  columns = line.split('\t'); //Assuming 1-based array, so indexes 1-4
  col2values = columns[2].split(',');
  for each value in col2values:
    OutputFile.WriteLine(columns[1]+'\t'+value+'\t'+columns[3]+'\t'+columns[4]);
```

If multiple columns can have multiple values, simply put another loop inside the for each.

Comment: Yeah a script would work too - was just hoping that a Regex would do the trick.